# How to check if a value entered is an integer or string when using input

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a program where you guess a randomly generated number between 1 and 100:

```
from random import randint
play='y'
print 'Guess a number between 1 and 100'

while play=='y':
    x = randint(1,100)
    guess=1000
    while guess != x:
        guess=input('Guess: ')
        if guess < x:
            print 'Higher'
        if guess > x:
            print 'Lower'
    print 'You got it! Good Job! The number was ' + str(x)
    play=raw_input('Would you like to play again(y/n)?: ')

raw_input("Press <enter> to exit")
```

when the user enters a guess that is not an integer how do I print That is not a number, then allow them to continue guessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while True` loop to repeat the question until it `breaks`. Only way to break the loop is if `try` does not raise a `ValueError`. `int()` raises an error when it gets something like `'hello'` or `'1.2'`.

Also, use `raw_input` instead of `input` (note: raw_input assigns a string to `guess`).

```
while True:    
    guess=raw_input('Guess: ')
    try:
        int(guess)        
        break
    except ValueError:
        print '\nNot an int, try again.'
```

More specifically, insert this after `while guess != x:` and before `if guess < x`.